# positioning dialog

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to position a dialog in jQuery and I have the following code. It doesn't seem to be doing what I expect it to do. I just need the dialog to either be centered or appear at the top left corner of my body.

Here is the code I have

```
    agreeDialog = $j('#termsOfAgreementConfirm').dialog({
                modal: true,
                autoOpen:false,
                resizable:false,
                width : 1000,
                height :400,
                stack:false,
                closeOnEscape:false,
                title:"Terms of Usage",
                open: function(event, ui) {

                    $j('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();

                },
                buttons: {

                    Disagree: function() {
                        disagree.dialog('open');
                        disagree.dialog('moveToTop');

                    },


                    Agree: function() {
                        $j(this).dialog('close');
                        $j.cookie("agree", "Y");
                        new Ajax.Request('/myballback/user/ajaxUpdateAgreementForUser',
                                {
                                    onSuccess:function(resp) {
                                    },
                                    onError: function(resp) {
                                        alert("Error:" + resp.toJSON());
                                        return;
                                    },
                                    asynchronous:true,
                                    evalScripts:true
                                });
                        $j(this).dialog('close');

                    }
                }
            });


var x = jQuery(agreeDialog).position().left + jQuery(agreeDialog).outerWidth();
            var y = jQuery(agreeDialog).position().top - jQuery(document).scrollTop();               //agreeDialog.dialog({width:width, height:height ,position:[posX, posY]});


            agreeDialog.dialog('option', 'position',[x, y]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try with:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position", ['left','top'] );
```

or

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position", 'center' );
```

Comment: when I do left top. What it does it does move the dialog but it moves it to the left edge of the browser window but the dialog is still positioned to the bottom of my page. Does it matter as to how and where my div is defined for the dialog ?

Comment: Do any of your own CSS rules act on the `dialog` `div`?

Comment: Agree with @jakeclarkson. Check that there is no other styles conflicting.

Comment: I don't think so they do but let me check on that

Comment: I found the answer to it. I just had to execute this code when the window had finished loading. The positioning was working but since the page had not completed loading other divs which were loading their data, were pushing this dialog to the bottom. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Glad it's sorted. As a rule of thumb always put this kind of stuff in `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`.

Comment: That is what I was doing before but  I have a AJAX request to display an image and some other data. While the Image is still being fetched, the dialog is displayed, when the image is displayed, that pushed the dialog from its original position and hence I had to put it in window.load()

Comment: @allthenutsandbolts That's correct. If you populate the dialog via ajax make sure all the content has been added to the jqueryui dialog before showing it. Othewise, the dimensions and positioning will be off.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`position`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) property of the jQuery `dialog` to achieve this; something like:

```
$j('#termsOfAgreementConfirm').dialog({
    ...
    position: "center",
    ....
});
```

From the [jQueryUI docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/):

> Specifies where the dialog should be displayed. Possible values:
>
> 1) a single string representing position within viewport: 'center', 'left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'.
>
> 2) an array containing an x,y coordinate pair in pixel offset from left, top corner of viewport (e.g. [350,100])
>
> 3) an array containing x,y position string values (e.g. ['right','top'] for top right corner)

Comment: I have tried all those options and nothing seems to be working.. Here is what I see. My page has some ajax calls which displays other divs, once those divs are rendered the dialog moves a bit from the original position where it opens but I don't see that setting any of the options on the dialog sets to the top or center.

Comment: What CSS `position` property does your `div` have?

Comment: I don't have any position property on the div defined ? Do I have to define ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to; have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvuyH/) for an example. If you right click on the div and click "Inspect Element" does it show you any `position` property it has inherited from another CSS rule?